# Kafka streams read & write to separate cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

a similar question has been answered before but the solution doesn't work for my use case.

We run 2 Kafka clusters each in 2 separate DCs. Our overall incoming traffic is split between these 2 DCs.

I'd be running separate Kafka streaming app in each DC to transform that data and want to write to a Kafka topic **in a single DC**. 
How can I achieve that?

Ultimately we'd be indexing the kafka topic data in Druid. Its not possible to run separate Druid clusters since we are trying to aggregate the data.

I've read that its not possible with a single Kafka stream. Is there a way I can use another Kafka stream to read from DC1 and write to DC2 kafka cluster ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote yourself, you cannot use the Kafka Streams API to read from Kafka cluster A and write to a different Kafka cluster B.

Instead, if you want to move data between Kafka clusters (whether it's in the same DC or across DCs) you should use a tool such as Apache Kafka's [Mirror Maker](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330) or [Confluent Replicator](https://docs.confluent.io/5.3.0/multi-dc-replicator/index.html).

Comment: thanks, trying to understand this. Say I am writing to topic 1(DC1) with Kafka streaming app.
If I were to set up a Mirror from topic 2(DC2) to topic 1(DC1), and , I'd expect this to create a merged stream, which has data from DC1 + DC2. Does it work the way I expect?

Comment: Yes. This should work, though of course it depends on the setup (e.g. topic 2 and topic 1 should have the same number of partitions and the same partitioning scheme).